# Codeigniter: Order by ascending date

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-order-by

Hi this is my model code for ordering and getting the data:

```
$this->db->order_by($oBy, "asc");
$query = $this->db->get('books');
```

Everything is working fine, however in my database i am storing the date as a string, e.g. 01-Jan-2014.

Therefore when i order the date it will order it by the day and not year, may i know how can i solve it by sorting by the year, however the data will still display out as 01-Jan-2014 and also it will be displayed in ascending order? Thank you!

Error:[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be storing your date as a string. Use one of the date formats your database supports. Then you can use the date functions available in your database to format the field however you like it and be able to order it in whatever what you desire.

Comment: Why not just write the full DB query, then at the end add ORDER BY `day` ASC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('str_to_date('.$oBy.', "%d-%b-%Y") day',false);//select your colum as new column name wich is converted as str ot date
//you can do select more.
$this->db->order_by('day','ASC');
$query = $this->db->get('books');
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: The error message means you did not made select other columns.You did not read what I said with 2nd comment of the solution.add this line `$this->db->select('books.*')`. before `this->db->order_by('day','ASC');` this line

Comment: Yup it worked thank you! :) Sorry but i am extremely bad at SQL query.

Comment: The one who gave downvote at least let me know the reason so that I can learn what wrong I did.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that $oBy is your column name

```
$this->db->order_by("str_to_date(" . $oBy . ", '%d-%b-%Y')", "asc");
```

%d =    Day of the month, numeric (00..31)

%b =    Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)

%Y = Year, numeric, four digits

Comment: The solution idea is ok. But it will produce error.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Couldn't test it myself, but yes I understand now i've seen your answer? Thx.