# Data sorting by current date in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I've got a sorting problem. I get data properly from the database, but the records are not sorted as I want: current date records displayed first and then other records.

I've tried to use `order_by` but later date records are displayed first. I want to get current date records first. How to achieve it...??

See my model.

```
public function getshopsponsered()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('shop_sponsered');
    $this->db->order_by('startdate', 'DESC');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $shop_list = array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $sm = new Shop_sponsered_model();
        $sm->setId($row->id);
        $sm->setStartdate($row->startdate);
        $sm->setEnddate($row->enddate);
        $sm->setDisplayIndex($row->display_index);

        //get business name//
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('business');
        $this->db->where('id',$row->businessid);
        $query = $this->db->get()->row();
        if($query > 0)
        {
            $sm->setBusinessid($query->name);
        }
        array_push($shop_list,$sm);
    }
    return $shop_list;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381738/codeigniter-order-by-ascending-date

Comment: Do you need only results which less or equals then today?

Answer (score 0):

change the `$query` instead of.

```
$query_outter = $this->db->get();

$shop_list = array();
foreach($query_outter->result() as $row)
{...}
```